# A live image feed in Android?

Tags: java, android, image, feed, live

What would be some ways to create an application that goes and fetches images (using URIs, that's the only way I've come across) so that the app's company can change the images without requiring alterations to the android code?

I've looked at URL redirection but it does not seem quite reliable.

(Each time the app starts, it goes and fetches the image for display)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Tumblr API achieved what I desired. It allows the fetching of the 6 most recent posts of a particular blog as JSON data. Recursively parsing the JSON received allows the program to dig in and use the URLs for a particular resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Your app would pull images from

```
http://company.comm/images/1 
http://company.comm/images/2
...  
http://company.comm/images/n
```

and you would have a website/service that would allow to upload and set live images.

Comment: The company I'm talking about uses a blogspot website. Any tips on where I can find such a website/service to allow stable URLS for customizable images?

Comment: @ChrisZhang what I had in mind is that if your company had web hosting you could just upload the files to sites root/images, or you would write/develop the site or service to automate this. I am not aware of any existing online services that would allow you to upload the images and get them with predictable url pattern, usually they give back urls with random ids.

Comment: The company also has a facebook page with images. Is there anyway to be able to fetch these images without log-in.

Comment: Would having the company post its images on a tumblr site also be an option? I could learn the Tumblr api to pull off the most recent 6 posts, say, and use that in my app.

Comment: @ChrisZhang It's possible to consume images from anywhere, the question is whether you can predict the urls for these images so that you don't have to make changes to your Android app configuration. Regarding tumblr - I don't know since I never used it, but I doubt you need to use any complicated api, simple http get would do. But from engineering standpoint, I would recommend against hosting images anywhere where you don't have full control, since any change to image path or access method would break your app.